# C# creating shortcut error

Tags: c#

I'm using the following code to create shortcuts for several files and copying them to the startup folder. The program runs on windows XP, and is built using .net framework 2.0.

Creating shortcut code

```
try
{
    object shDesktop = (object)"Desktop";
    WshShell shell = new WshShell();
    //Shorcut name
    string shortcutAddress = @"C:\Documents and Settings\Astrophysics Inc\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\Shortcut to " + s + ".lnk";
    IWshShortcut shortcut = (IWshShortcut)shell.CreateShortcut(shortcutAddress);
    shortcut.Description = "New shortcut for a Notepad";
    shortcut.Hotkey = "Ctrl+Shift+N";
    //File path
    shortcut.TargetPath = @"C:\Program Files\" +path+ @"\" + s + ".exe";
    shortcut.Save();
}
catch (Exception) { };
```

So the error is the following:
If i launch the file from the shortcut, I can see it in processes but i cannot have any readings from it. However if i go to properties and find the shortcut's location (actual file), and open it from its own folder, the application works.
I tried creating the same shortcut physically (not using C#), and it works as intended.

What do you think the problem might be from? Tried running it several times and got the same problem. And yes I am certain that the shortcut is linked to the same file.

Comment: It's working by me, though I'm not on XP. How does it react with the  WorkingDirectory property set?

Comment: It works on me also on windows 7 perfectly.
Additionally i do not get any error, the shortcut is created, the file is booted but not functioning properly when ran from this specific shortcut. I will try to set the working directory property and let you know.

Comment: @JedBurke adding the working directory fixed the issue! Thanks!

Comment: No problem, I'm glad it's working.